# Getting a Â character before the degree symbol

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpu-word

I am trying to concatenate the degree symbol to a string so I can write it to a word document. I have tried to do it like this.

```
degreeChar = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
print degreeChar.encode('UTF-8')
```

The output I get from this is `Â°` and I am not sure why `Â` is showing up.  What am I doing wrong? Very frustrated!

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that it is your Operating System and/or command environment that is the problem as the above works fine in Konsole on Kubuntu - are you running WinXP by any chance?

Answer (score 6):

When you do this:

```
>>> degreeChar = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
```

`degreeChar` is a one-character Unicode string—in particular, `u'°'`:

```
>>> len(degreeChar)
1
>>> ord(degreeChar)
176
```

When you encode it to UTF-8, you get a 2-byte UTF-8 byte string:

```
>>> dc = degreeChar.encode('UTF-8')
>>> len(dc)
2
>>> ord(dc[0]), ord(dc[1])
(194, 176)
```

As UTF-8, that pair of bytes means `u'°'`. But as, say, Latin-1 or cp1252, the exact same pair of bytes means `u'Â°'`. That's the whole point of different encodings—the same byte sequence means different things in different encodings. To see the details:

```
>>> dc2 = dc.decode('latin-1')
>>> len(dc2)
2
>>> ord(dc2[0]), ord(dc2[1])
(194, 176)
```

So, what happens if you try to `print` the UTF-8 string to a cp1252 terminal? Or save it to a binary file that you then open as a cp1252 text file? Well, you get `Â°` of course.

---

So, how do you solve this?

Well, just don't try to print UTF-8-encoded bytes to a cp1252 terminal! If Python has successfully guessed your terminal's encoding, just print it as a Unicode string in the first place:

```
>>> print u'°'
°
```

If not, you either need to fix your configuration so Python *does* guess your terminal's encoding correctly (easy on most *nix systems, not so much on Windows…), or specify it manually, or just encode to the *right* encoding instead of the wrong one:

```
>>> print u'°'.encode('cp1252')
°
```

Answer (score 0):

```
degreeChar = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
print degreeChar
```

It should be fine as unicode ... at least on windows 7 this command works as expected

Comment: When I print chr(176) it will print just the degree symbol but when I try to write it to word document it fails.

Comment: what do you mean it fails?  open the file as "wb"... do you mean an actual .docx? how are you writing to it?

Comment: I am using python docx to create the document and I read that I should use &#176 but I am not sure how I can concatenate that with a string.

Answer (score 0):

The document where `°` is located is encoded with UTF-8, but the interpreter assumes it as different.

In my case I just added UTF-8 BOM mark to that document, so the interpreter become aware of the content encoding.